# Split Input Array Values - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an input field wherein users can enter multiple inputs with `comma` in between.

```
<div class="container">
    
    Enter your values:<input type="text" multiple #inputCheck>
    <input type="submit"(click)="sendInput(inputCheck.value)">

</div>
```

These inputs are to be stored in the following array.

```
 arrayStored=[]
```

I have tried using the below code but the inputs are not divided in the array and the whole input is seen as a single element inside an array. I need to divide the input into multiple elements and store them inside the array.

```
     sendInput(event:any){
     this.inputGiven = event;
     this.arrayStored.push(this.inputGiven);
```

**Example**: If a user enters `SAM,ALEX7,23` and clicks submit , the array should store it as `arrayStored=["SAM","ALEX7,"23"]` but now it is being stored as `arrayStored=["SAM,ALEX7,23"]`. How do I split the input and store them as an individual element inside the array ?

Comment: try `this.arrayStored = [...this.arrayStored, ...this.inputGiven.split(",")];`

Comment: It worked but now, if I click submit button again, it replicates the values inside the array. Example: ["SAM","ALEX7,"23","SAM","ALEX7,"23"] I need the values to only appear once even if the submit button is clicked multiple times. Any idea on this please?

Comment: try this then. 
`this.inputGiven.split(",").forEach(value => {
  !this.arrayStored.includes(value) && this.arrayStored.push(value)
});`

Comment: `forEach(...) is not iterable (cannnot read propery undefiined)` It didn't work.

Comment: it was untested. anyway you got your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Thanks for your help mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the elements in an array like so:

```
 this.arrayStored.concat(this.inputGiven.spilt(“,”));
```

and to remove any duplicates from the array you can convert it into a set and back into an array like below:

```
 this.arrayStored = Array.from(new Set(this.arrayStored));
```